# Bundle Addons with Firefox Mobile (Fennec)

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon, build-process, firefox-addon-sdk

How to Bundle Addons with Firefox Mobile (Fennec) for Android ?
I would like to include several add-ons on the build process in a away that users could start using them immediately.
I've searched Mozilla Wiki and couldn't find any relevant information about this. tks.

Comment: Do you mean to build an apk of Fennec with addons preinstalled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer:

> To create a distribution build locally, put your distribution folder
>   at objdir/dist/bin/distribution, then package the app as you normally
>   would. The distribution files will be copied out to
>   /data/data/org.mozilla.fennec_yourname/distribution, and they will
>   override a system distribution if it is present.
>
> Add-ons do no need to be listed in any file. Instead, include them in
>   an extensions directory as follows, and they will be automatically
>   loaded:
>
> - distribution/    * extensions/
>
>   - someaddon@somedomain.com.xpi
>   - ...

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Distribution_Files#Add-ons