# How do I include extensions with a custom build of Firefox for Android (Fennec)?

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon, build-process, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to include an extension in a custom build of Firefox for Android (Fennec) so that when the user installs the APK, the Fennec browser already has the extension installed.

I'm using a baseline of Fennec v48.0b6. It might be worth drawing attention to the fact that this is beta build, although I don't expect it should make a difference.

### The simple way this *should* work

Documentation for such a process does seem to exist but I'm having trouble getting it to work. The [Mozilla Wiki has a guide](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Distribution_Files#Testing_a_distribution_locally) to this. It, and other hints surrounding the solution I've found, indicate that I need a 'distribution' folder somewhere in the Firefox workspace. I have a folder structure as follows:

- firefox-48.0b6

  - custom-dist

    - assets

      - distribution

        - preferences.json
        - extensions

          - my-extension.xpi

where 'firefox-48.0b6' is the root folder containing all of the source directories such as b2g, browser, chrome, mobile, and so on. This matches the [sample directory structure provided by Mozilla](https://github.com/mozilla/fennec-distribution-sample).

I've added the following line to my mozconfig:

```
ac_add_options --with-android-distribution-directory="/data/workspaces/firefox/firefox-48.0b6/custom-dist"
```

which correctly tracks the absolute distribution location. If this path doesn't point to a distribution then I get an error when I run `mach configure`, so it must be being read.

The extension's XPI name needs to match the ID (as indicated on the same Mozilla Wiki page) given in the extension's install.rdf file. I've changed the install.rdf file and the XPI name so that they match.

Having done all of this I still don't see my extension in the list of add-ons when I install the APK.

### What I've done to try to get this to work

I've tried a few additional things (none of which have solved my problem):

- Changing the `MOZ_ANDROID_PACKAGE_INSTALL_BOUNCER` flag to False in mobile/android/moz.configure. This is mentioned in the Mozilla Wiki. Bugzilla seems to indicate that there [is a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1278959) still present in this version so this is probably not worth further enquiry.
- Having read the comments (specifically [comment 2](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1278959#c2)) on the linked bug from the above point, I've tried setting changing the `MOZ_ANDROID_PACKAGE_INSTALL_BOUNCER=1` to `MOZ_ANDROID_PACKAGE_INSTALL_BOUNCER=` in mobile/android/confvars.sh so that it's not read as a truthy value.
- I've tried deleting `MOZ_ANDROID_PACKAGE_INSTALL_BOUNCER` from confvars.sh altogether.
- Tried putting the distribution folder into objdir-droid/dist/bin as indicated in [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844279/bundle-addons-with-firefox-mobile-fennec) question and answer. It's notable that this is not mentioned on the Mozilla Wiki. From [this Bugzilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1163082) report it looks like it relates to an old method of doing things.

### Where I'm stuck

Ultimately, I still don't have a build of Firefox for Android that has the extension included by default. There are a couple of points that might be the source of the problem, but I don't know enough about the process to say for sure, namely:

- I'm using a beta build of Firefox for Android as my baseline. **Will this cause problems for the purposes of including a distribution?**
- I push the APK directly to /system/priv-app rather than installing it (either within the Android OS itself or by using `adb install`). **Does this make a difference as to whether the distribution is applied?**

**What have I missed that will get this working?**

### Edit

I've since realised that I also need a minimal preferences.json file in the distribution directory. However, including this hasn't solved the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you.
After extracting the apk file into a folder, I found that my xpi file is not included.
Maybe there is a bug related to fennec packaging scripts about option "--with-android-distribution-directory"? Maybe dig more into the scripts implementation is another choice. Also we can try to install the xpi ourselves by referencing the following js script which is implemented in fennec:

mozilla-central/mobile/android/chrome/content/browser.js

```
installDistroAddons: Task.async(function* () {
const PREF_ADDONS_INSTALLED = "distribution.addonsInstalled";
try {
  let installed = Services.prefs.getBoolPref(PREF_ADDONS_INSTALLED);
  if (installed) {
    return;
  }
} catch (e) {
  Services.prefs.setBoolPref(PREF_ADDONS_INSTALLED, true);
}

let distroPath;
try {
  distroPath = FileUtils.getDir("XREAppDist", ["extensions"]).path;

  let info = yield OS.File.stat(distroPath);
  if (!info.isDir) {
    return;
  }
} catch (e) {
  return;
}

let it = new OS.File.DirectoryIterator(distroPath);
try {
  yield it.forEach(entry => {
    // Only support extensions that are zipped in .xpi files.
    if (entry.isDir || !entry.name.endsWith(".xpi")) {
      dump("Ignoring distribution add-on that isn't an XPI: " + entry.path);
      return;
    }

    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      AddonManager.getInstallForFile(new FileUtils.File(entry.path), resolve);
    }).then(install => {
      let id = entry.name.substring(0, entry.name.length - 4);
      if (install.addon.id !== id) {
        Cu.reportError("File entry " + entry.path + " contains an add-on with an incorrect ID");
        return;
      }
      this.pendingAddonInstalls.add(install);
      install.install();
    }).catch(e => {
      Cu.reportError("Error installing distribution add-on: " + entry.path + ": " + e);
    });
  });
} finally {
  it.close();
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that the IceCat mobile browser for Android is such a derivative that includes preinstalled extensions. Keep in mind that they're based on the ESR channel so you might need to mess with their build scripts a bit, but I'd take a look at their implementation. Here's the project page:

https://www.gnu.org/software/gnuzilla/

If that's no good then maybe take a look at the TOR firefox distribution (I'm pretty sure they include noscript by default).